# Gradient text cross browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, gradient

I'm trying to make a menu bar with a horizontal gradient. I've had some success using `-webkit-background-clip` but that won't work in Firefox.

I found a jQuery plugin pxgradient that's cross browser compatible but I can't get it to span the gradient over several `li` elements. See the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vnv4nyhj/10/

```
function gradient1() {
    $(".test").pxgradient({
        step: 10,
        colors: ["#ff0066", "#2850FF"],
        dir: "x"
    });
};
```

I want the gradient to be more like the top one. Ideally I'd like the border-bottom to include the same gradient on hover but I can possibly live in a world without that.

PS- the `font-awesome` icon is there only because it gave me problems earlier so I included now to make sure it works.

**Update:**
Another possible idea I was playing with was to read the number of elements, then divide the colours per element and use the nth-child() selector to assign each color.

```
<script>
//Get number of list items
var menuItems = $("li").children().length;

//Convert colors to hex
hexString1 = '2850FF';
hexString2 = 'FF0066';
color1 = parseInt(hexString1, 16);
color2 = parseInt(hexString2, 16);

//Calculate difference in colors and color step
colorDifference = color2 - color1;
colorStep = colorDifference / (menuItems - 1);
colorStep = parseInt(colorStep);

//Loop through elements and apply gradients
for (i = 0; i < menuItems; i++) {
    newColor1 = color1 + (i * colorStep);
    newColor2 = color1 color2 -1;
    gradientStart = newColor1.toString(16);
    gradientEnd = newColor2.toString(16);

    //use gradientStart and gradientEnd as colors in the function, not sure on this part yet

}

</script>
```

It's seems so overkill though, there must be a simpler solution? Also an element with many characters will have a relatively slow gradient compared to one with a few characters. That could possibly be fixed by counting the numbers of characters per element, but it just all seems rather inefficient.

Comment: Hmm messing around with your Fiddle I removed the HREF attribute from the link which makes the text look like you want but when I tried to inject the URL after the pxgradiant call is made and it doesnt work. [You can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/vnv4nyhj/11/) If find a work around or a different way, ill let you know.

Comment: Thanks for having a look.
I've had a different idea but how can I respond to my own question with the regular editor? Long time reader of stackoverlow, first time poster.

Comment: @Robert Edit your question if you need to clarify something. The edit "button" is located beneath the tags, if you're having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution, that will work in FF, Chrome, and Safari, using blend modes.

The trick is that the gradient is set under the a, in the ul .

Setting mix-blend-mode: screen, this colors will show only on the black places (the text, and the border when hovered)

```css
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue);
}
li {
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    background-color: white;  
    box-shadow: 8px 0px 0px white;
}
li, li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
}
li:hover a {
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nav 5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No way! I had given up hope for a simple solution like yours.